# Lodash set every element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Is there a way to use the string notation in the _.set method to match all items in a nested array?

(e.g. hopefully similar to MongoDB's [positional all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) operator)

```
const doc = {
  nested: [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]
}

_.set(doc, "nested.$[].a", 5)

// console.log(doc)
// {
//   nested: [{a : 5}, {a: 5}, {a: 5}]
// }
```

Comment: I don't think there is any inbuild function in lodash. you have to use loop for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't set every element in a nested array with the `.set()` method, but you can do this instead:

```js
const doc = {
  nested: [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]
}

// Your attempt.
// _.set(doc, "nested.$[].a", 5)

// Just use a .map() with .assign() instead.
const doc2 = _.assign({}, doc, {
  nested: _.map(doc.nested, (obj) => _.assign({}, obj, { a: 5 }))
});

console.log(doc2)
// {
//   nested: [{a : 5}, {a: 5}, {a: 5}]
// }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```